# Parse text vb.net to strings

Tags: vb.net, linq

Lets say i have a string which goes like

```
<image1>C:\images\dropbox\lister\4844-001.jpg</image1><image2>C:\images\dropbox\lister\4844-002.jpg</image2><image3>C:\images\dropbox\lister\4844-003.jpg</image3><image4>C:\images\dropbox\lister\4844-004.jpg</image4>
```

It contains from Image1 to ImageN

I need to check through each image path and check if the image on that path really exist.

How to loop through that ?

I think that finding the index of word  and  and pulling all text between is the slowest way.

Can you suggest anything beside that ?

```
Private Function Word(source As String, start As String, ends As String) As String
        Dim sSource As String = source
        Dim sDelimStart As String = start
        Dim sDelimEnd As String = ends
        Dim nIndexStart As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimStart)
        Dim nIndexEnd As Integer = sSource.IndexOf(sDelimEnd)

        If nIndexStart > -1 AndAlso nIndexEnd > -1 Then
            Dim res As String = Strings.Mid(sSource, nIndexStart + sDelimStart.Length + 1, nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length) 'Crop the text between
            Return res
        Else
            Return ""
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: I don't think speed is the main concern of the solution. If you have a slow way coded up, use it to save yourself some time. Otherwise, use [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) to parse your HTML-like syntax, and iterate through text content that the parser is going to give you.

Comment: If you took into consideration the delimiter's indexed suffix, `.IndexOf() + .SubString()` are OK. You can also Regex it (something like `<image\d+>(.*?)<\/`). Each `[Match].Group(1)` will contain the file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this I converted your string to a XElement, then iterated each of the imageN nodes.  This should work so long as your input string is as you specified.

```
    Dim s As String
    s = "<image1>C:\images\dropbox\lister\4844-001.jpg</image1><image2>C:\images\dropbox\lister\4844-002.jpg</image2><image3>C:\images\dropbox\lister\4844-003.jpg</image3><image4>C:\images\dropbox\lister\4844-004.jpg</image4>"
    s = "<FOO>" & s
    s = s & "</FOO>"
    Dim fooXE As XElement = XElement.Parse(s)
    For Each el As XElement In fooXE.Elements
        ' Debug.WriteLine(el.Value)
        If IO.File.Exists(el.Value) Then
            'the path exists
        End If
    Next
```